# HTML element to use as a Javascript message display

Tags: javascript, textbox

I have a message display field on my website that I'd like to change the value of via JS.

I've been using just a textfield, disabling it, and modifying the value via a JS function (after using a little CSS to make it not *look* like a text field):

```
<input type="text" id="message" style="background: white; color: black" size="50" disabled>
```

There has to be a better way (for instance, formatting is tricky whenever the message runs over the specified size), but I can't think of it off the top of my head. Can anyone point me in a better direction? Thanks!

FYI: I am doing a timer function which I'd like to look something like "HH:MM:SS | 'my message here'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the contents of any element with `innerHTML`. So instead of messing with a form input, you could just have this:

```
<div id="message"></div>
```

And set it via JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'This message is awesome.';
```

And you would get this result:

```
<div id="message">This message is awesome.</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use a styled span and set it's innerHtml.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery (I totally suggest using a framework like jQuery, to avoid cross-browser problems with innerHTML), this is reeeeeally simple:

```
<span id="timer"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#timer").text("HH:MM:SS | your message here");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is pretty much the only place on the project where I'm using JS, so JQuery is probably a bit more than I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), which has a console for log messages that can be placed in the main page or in a separate window.

Disclosure: I wrote it.